# Look up a date value from each cell in a column and return a year date dependent upon where date falls between two dates

Tags: excel-formula

I'm wanting to add formula to locate the Policy Year in each cell in column B (starting in B2) which is determined from interrogating the date shown in the corresponding cell in Column A and then checking whether it sits in a range (inception date and expiry date) D2:E5 The Policy Year sits in C2:C5 I've shown the values I'd expect the formula in the cells in column B to draw from Column C.

COLUMN A          COLUMN B   EXPECTED VALUE   COLUMN C     COLUMN D          COLUMN E
2 April 2017                 2016             2016         5 December 2016   4 December 2017
5 June 2017                  2016             2017         5 December 2017   4 December 2018
6 December 2017              2017             2018         5 December 2018   4 December 2019
4 January 2018               2017             2019         5 December 2019   4 December 2020
6 August 2018                2017
4 December 2018              2017
29 December 2018             2018
6 March 2020                 2019

Comment: =IFERROR(@INDEX($C$2:$C$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($D$2:$D$6)-ROW($A$2)+1)/(($E$2:$E$6<=$A1)*($G$2:$G$5>=$A2)),1)),"")

Comment: The above formula was recommended by a friend but doesn't seem to work and I don't fully understand it anyway.